# Adicionar id dinâmico com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Apareceu a necessidade de eu criar uma view que eu preciso adicionar inputs através de um botão, onde o usuário vai digitar o nome do campo que ele quer adicionar, esse nome vai aparecer em uma label em cima do input, e o id desse input também tem que ser criado dinamicamente, exemplo (id="item1", id="item2")

Segue um código HTML com jQuery que está adicionando o input já, só não estou conseguindo adicionar a label com o nome que o usuário digitou no input principal e gerar os id dinamicamente para serem enviados pro PHP.

```js
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');
    $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function () {
              $('<p>'+
                  '<label>Nome dinamico</label>' +
          '<input type="text" id="inputeste" size="20" value="" placeholder="" /> '+
          '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">'+
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> '+
        'Remover Campo'+
          '</a>'+
    '</p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function () {
          $(this).parents('p').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title>Adicionando Campo Dinâmico</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" id="addInput">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Adicionar Campo
   </a>
   <br/>
   <div id="dynamicDiv">
    <p>
           <input type="text" id="inputeste" size="20" value="" placeholder="" />
           <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Remover Campo
     </a>
          </p>
      </div>
       </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `window.prompt` para capturar o nome do *label* (já que no seu HTML não há o campo para esta função); e poderá utilizar `$("#dynamicDiv > p").length` para capturar o número atual de elementos e nomear o atributo `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só pegar o texto do input com `$("#inputeste").val()` para colocar na label concatenando na string a ser inserida.

Para gerar as ids em ordem, sugiro uma função separada para isso, para que ela possa ser chamada quando você inserir ou remover itens. A função irá percorrer todos os inputs (menos o primeiro) e colocar ids em ordem: `item1`, `item2` etc.

```js
$(function () {
   
   var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');

   // função que organiza as ids
   function ids(){
      scntDiv.find("input:not(:first)").each(function(i){
         this.id = "item"+ parseInt(i+1);
      });
   }
   
   
   $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function () {
   
      var nome = $("#inputeste").val();
   
      $('<p>'+
      '<label>'+nome+'</label>' +
      '<input type="text" size="20" value="" placeholder="" /> '+
      '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">'+
      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> '+
      'Remover Campo'+
      '</a>'+
      '</p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
      
      ids();
      
      return false;
   });

   $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function () {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      ids();
      return false;
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title>Adicionando Campo Dinâmico</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" id="addInput">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    Adicionar Campo
   </a>
   <br/>
   <div id="dynamicDiv">
    <p>
           <input type="text" id="inputeste" size="20" value="" placeholder="" />
           <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Remover Campo
     </a>
          </p>
      </div>
       </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui! Muito obrigado